# ReadOnlyKeyValueStore from a KTable using spring-kafka

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I am migrating a Kafka Streams implementation which uses pure Kafka apis to use spring-kafka instead as it's incorporated in a spring-boot application.

Everything works fine the Stream, GlobalKTable, branching that I have all works perfectly fine but I am having a hard time incorporating a ReadOnlyKeyValueStore. Based on the spring-kafka documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.6.10/reference/html/#streams-spring

It says:

> If you need to perform some KafkaStreams operations directly, you can
> access that internal KafkaStreams instance by using
> StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.getKafkaStreams(). You can autowire
> StreamsBuilderFactoryBean bean by type, but you should be sure to use
> the full type in the bean definition.

Based on that I tried to incorporate it to my example as in the following fragments below:

```
@Bean(name = KafkaStreamsDefaultConfiguration.DEFAULT_STREAMS_CONFIG_BEAN_NAME)
    public KafkaStreamsConfiguration defaultKafkaStreamsConfig() {
        Map<String, Object> props = defaultStreamsConfigs();
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "quote-stream");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, SpecificAvroSerde.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "stock-quotes-stream-group");
        return new KafkaStreamsConfiguration(props);
    }

    @Bean(name = KafkaStreamsDefaultConfiguration.DEFAULT_STREAMS_BUILDER_BEAN_NAME)
    public StreamsBuilderFactoryBean defaultKafkaStreamsBuilder(KafkaStreamsConfiguration defaultKafkaStreamsConfig) {
        return new StreamsBuilderFactoryBean(defaultKafkaStreamsConfig);
    }
```

...

```
final GlobalKTable<String, LeveragePrice> leverageBySymbolGKTable = streamsBuilder
            .globalTable(KafkaConfiguration.LEVERAGE_PRICE_TOPIC,
                    Materialized.<String, LeveragePrice, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("leverage-by-symbol-table")
                            .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
                            .withValueSerde(leveragePriceSerde));

leveragePriceView = myKStreamsBuilder.getKafkaStreams().store("leverage-by-symbol-table", QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore());
```

But adding the StreamsBuilderFactoryBean(which seems to be needed to get a reference to KafkaStreams) definition causes an error:

```
The bean 'defaultKafkaStreamsBuilder', defined in class path resource [com/resona/springkafkastream/repository/KafkaConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [org/springframework/kafka/annotation/KafkaStreamsDefaultConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.
```

The issue is I don't want to control the lifecycle of the stream that's what I get with the plain Kafka APIs so I would like to get a reference to the default managed one as I want spring to manage it but whenever I try to expose the bean it gives the error. Any ideas on what's the correct approach to that using spring-kafka?

P.S - I am not interested in solutions using spring-cloud-stream I am looking for implementations of spring-kafka.

Comment: Try using the `@Primary` annotation on top of your `KafkaStreamsConfiguration` bean

Comment: Hi, tried that but then I get an error "Nullpointer" like if the streamsBuilder is not initialized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to define any new beans; something like this should work...

```
spring.application.name=quote-stream
spring.kafka.streams.properties.default.key.serde=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
spring.kafka.streams.properties.default.value.serde=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableKafkaStreams
public class So69669791Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So69669791Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    GlobalKTable<String, String> leverageBySymbolGKTable(StreamsBuilder sb) {
        return sb.globalTable("gkTopic",
                Materialized.<String, String, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>> as("leverage-by-symbol-table"));
    }

    private ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, String> leveragePriceView;

    @Bean
    StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.Listener afterStart(StreamsBuilderFactoryBean sbfb,
            GlobalKTable<String, String> leverageBySymbolGKTable) {

        StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.Listener listener = new StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.Listener() {

            @Override
            public void streamsAdded(String id, KafkaStreams streams) {
                leveragePriceView  = streams.store("leverage-by-symbol-table", QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore());
            }

        };
        sbfb.addListener(listener);
        return listener;
    }

    @Bean
    KStream<String, String> stream(StreamsBuilder builder) {
        KStream<String, String> stream = builder.stream("someTopic");
        stream.to("otherTopic");
        return stream;
    }

}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.